# Static file handler with path variables causes 404 error in Gorilla Mux

Tags: google-app-engine, go, gorilla

I need to use path variables in conjunction with a static file handler using [Gorilla Mux](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux), but I can't find any examples of how to do that.

Here's a working file handler without the path variables:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.PathPrefix("/discovery").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/discovery", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/dist")))).Methods("GET")
http.Handle("/", r)
```

I tried adding the path variables, like this:

```
r.PathPrefix("/discovery/{type}/{value}").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/discovery", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/dist")))).Methods("GET")
```

But then /discovery gives a 404 error.
I need to match paths like:

/discovery

/discovery/hash/umbrella

And they all need to point to the path "static/dist", so the logic can be passed along to React Router.

Comment: What is the `handlers` config in your `app.yaml` file?

Comment: my app.yaml has just the basic:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app